# Conditional migration of a class in Dymola when parameter is String

Tags: migration, modelica, dymola

Library migration: Is it possible to convert a component to a different class when the condition parameter is of type String? Trying something like

```
convertClassIf("OldClass",
               "stringParameter",
               "blue",
               "NewClass");
```

fails. This shall trigger conversion of `OldClass(stringParameter=\"blue\")` into `NewClass()`.

I'm using Dymola 2022x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this does not work in Dymola 2022x.

According to [Modelica Specification 3.5](https://specification.modelica.org/maint/3.5/annotations.html#conversion-rules) it should be possible:

```
The old element should be of a Boolean, Integer, String, or enumeration type and the match is based
on the literal value of the modiﬁer. For string elements the value argument to convertClassIf shall be
up-quoted, e.g. "\"My String\"" ...
```

So this should have worked (And maybe it will in future Dymola versions):

```
convertClassIf("OldClass",
               "stringParameter",
               "\"blue\"",
               "NewClass");
```

But Dymola 2022x just marks classes as modified without changing anything.

Comment: Your are right. And my mistake: I have of course testet both quoted and non quoted version but neither works.

Comment: It is planned to work in Dymola 2023.

Comment: @HansOlsson Great, that was a missing info. Many thanks.